# How to create multiple textfields in Carbon?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, macos-carbon

I want to be able to create a dialog box with 2 textfields in it.
I can create a dialog with 1 textfield with code below,

```
const void* keys[] =
{
kCFUserNotificationAlertHeaderKey,
kCFUserNotificationAlertMessageKey,
kCFUserNotificationAlternateButtonTitleKey,
kCFUserNotificationTextFieldTitlesKey
};

const void* values[] =
{
titleStr,
messageStr,
CFSTR("Cancel"),
labelStr
};

 CFDictionaryRef elements = CFDictionaryCreate(0, keys, values, sizeof(keys)/sizeof(*keys), &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,&kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
          CFShow(elements);
```

When I add one more key-value pair, e.g. kCFUserNotificationTextFieldTitlesKey with some CFSTR(""), I do not see anything getting updated in the dialog box.

So how can we have multiple textfield, e.g. Username/password, in CFDitionaryCreate().

I read in the documentation that we can have multiple titleKeys with an array, but i am not sure how to do that.

I was able to add one field in the dialog `kCFUserNotificationProgressIndicatorValueKey` but not able to add same key again.

I am relatively new to OSX and carbon API (which i am aware that is been deprecated) 
I'd appreciate if I am pointed to the right resource or example which can help me achieve this.

Also, using Cocoa is not an option here. I need to achieve this using carbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value associated with the key `kCFUserNotificationTextFieldTitlesKey` or `kCFUserNotificationTextFieldValuesKey` would be an array of strings:

```
CFTypeRef values[2] = { CFSTR("one"), CFSTR("two") };
CFArrayRef valArray = CFArrayCreate( NULL, values, 2, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks );
```

By the way, you're using Core Foundation, not Carbon.  Not every C-based API is Carbon.

Comment: That worked, thanks! 
Would u recommend any reference book for learning Core Foundation and Carbon, I know its deprecated, I still want to go for it.

Comment: @2am, I don't know any books on the more recent Carbon stuff such as HIView.  I assume you are using Xcode 3.2.6, since more recent Xcodes can't handle Carbon nibs.  In the Xcode 3.2.6 doc reader, be sure to read the HIView Programming Guide and the Carbon Event Manager Programming Guide.